# inserting to database in one shot an array mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello all i am having a variable $document_ids=1,2,4,5,8,99,102 and i need to insert each of them individually to my database table like

```
$shaeredata=mysqli_query
($conn,"insert into docs (dcid,pid) values 
('$dcid','$pid'),('$dcid2','$pid'),('$dcid3','$pid'),('$dcid4','$pid')");
//dcid is each id from the variable $document_ids=1,1022,4,5,8,99,102  
//$dcid=1,dcid2=1022,$dcid3=4 ...... pid is same for all
```

the problem is that how do i put the values to database as i dont what document_id is going to be there it can be any seperated by coma.

```
$document_id=Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 4
[2] => 5
[3] => 999
[4] => 6
[5] => 7
[6] => 8
) // i have converted it to an array all of these are $dcid $pid=23 for all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you really mean that `$documement_ids is`array(1,2,4,5,8,99,102)`. If it's a string, you can use`explode` to split it into an array.

You can create an array of all the value pairs, and then use `implode` to connect them with commas.

```
$values = implode(',', array_map(function($dcid) use ($pid) {
    return "('$dcid', '$pid')";
}, $document_ids);
$sql = "INSERT INTO docs (dcid, pid) VALUES $values";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: is this possible to use more than two parameters in your function like if i want the $value to be like ('$dcid2','$pid','$something'),('$dcid3','$pid','$something') ???

Comment: You can add more variables to the `use()` list. `use($pid, $something)`.

Comment: And if you have multiple arrays, you can add them to `array_map()`, and add more function parameters.

Comment: can i also do something by which database insertion takes place only if $dcid is not already present with that perticular $pid ??

Comment: What i mean is that want to have unique combination of $dcid and $pid in my database

Comment: Make it a unique key, and use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip the ones that are duplicates.

Comment: i can not make $dcid in my database to be unique as the same data can be shared with some one else but not with the one with which it has already been shared ... the combination of $dcid and $pid should be unique not $dcid or $pid ...

Comment: Make a unique key on the list of columns that should be unique together. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dcid_pid ON docs (dcid, pid);`.

Comment: it ignores the full query (no insertion is done ) even if there is any one duplicate combo

Comment: No it doesn't, it just ignores the ones that would be duplicates.